# Unable to browse to SAMBA shares

Tags: samba, centos5

In my enviroment I have CentOS 5 installed with CUPS and SAMBA. I am unable to browse any SAMBA shares from any machine.

From Windows 8 and Windows Server 2008, I have tried the commands below

net view \\veculx1

net view \\172.19.50.30

However I receive the same error on both commands:

> System error 53 has occurred.
>
> The network path was not found.

From another CentOS server I tried running SMBCLEINT -L \\172.19.50.30

> Error connecting to 172.19.50.30 (No route to host) Connection to
>   172.19.50.30 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)

Pinging the server resolves and replies. I can also telnet and SSH into the server without issue.

Running testparm smb.conf shows no errors in my setup.

Below is the contents of smb.conf

```
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options (perhaps too
# many!) most of which are not shown in this example
#
# For a step to step guide on installing, configuring and using samba,
# read the Samba-HOWTO-Collection. This may be obtained from:
#  http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-HOWTO-Collection.pdf
#
# Many working examples of smb.conf files can be found in the
# Samba-Guide which is generated daily and can be downloaded from:
#  http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-Guide.pdf
#
# Any line which starts with a ; (semi-colon) or a # (hash)
# is a comment and is ignored. In this example we will use a #
# for commentry and a ; for parts of the config file that you
# may wish to enable
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command "testparm"
# to check that you have not made any basic syntactic errors.
#
#---------------
# SELINUX NOTES:
#
# If you want to use the useradd/groupadd family of binaries please run:
# setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on
#
# If you want to share home directories via samba please run:
# setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
#
# If you create a new directory you want to share you should mark it as
# "samba-share_t" so that selinux will let you write into it.
# Make sure not to do that on system directories as they may already have
# been marked with othe SELinux labels.
#
# Use ls -ldZ /path to see which context a directory has
#
# Set labels only on directories you created!
# To set a label use the following: chcon -t samba_share_t /path
#
# If you need to share a system created directory you can use one of the
# following (read-only/read-write):
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro on
# or
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
#
# If you want to run scripts (preexec/root prexec/print command/...) please
# put them into the /var/lib/samba/scripts directory so that smbd will be
# allowed to run them.
# Make sure you COPY them and not MOVE them so that the right SELinux context
# is applied, to check all is ok use restorecon -R -v /var/lib/samba/scripts
#
#--------------
#
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]
#--authconfig--start-line--

# Generated by authconfig on 2013/04/17 15:00:09
# DO NOT EDIT THIS SECTION (delimited by --start-line--/--end-line--)
# Any modification may be deleted or altered by authconfig in future

   workgroup = ******
   security = share
   idmap uid = 16777216-33554431
   idmap gid = 16777216-33554431
   template shell = /bin/false
   winbind use default domain = false
   winbind offline logon = false
   printing = bsd
#--authconfig--end-line--

# ----------------------- Network Related Options -------------------------
#
# workgroup = NT-Domain-Name or Workgroup-Name, eg: MIDEARTH
#
# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
#
# netbios name can be used to specify a server name not tied to the hostname
#
# Interfaces lets you configure Samba to use multiple interfaces
# If you have multiple network interfaces then you can list the ones
# you want to listen on (never omit localhost)
#
# Hosts Allow/Hosts Deny lets you restrict who can connect, and you can
# specifiy it as a per share option as well
#
;   workgroup = ****** 
    server string = Samba Server Version %v

;   netbios name = vdomlx1
;   interfaces = 172.19.210.30/24
;   hosts allow = 127. 192.168.12. 192.168.13.

# --------------------------- Logging Options -----------------------------
#
# Log File let you specify where to put logs and how to split them up.
#
# Max Log Size let you specify the max size log files should reach

    # logs split per machine
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
    # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
;   max log size = 50
    log level = 3
# ----------------------- Standalone Server Options ------------------------
#
# Security can be set to user, share(deprecated) or server(deprecated)
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.

;   security = share
    passdb backend = tdbsam


# ----------------------- Domain Members Options ------------------------
#
# Security must be set to domain or ads
#
# Use the realm option only with security = ads
# Specifies the Active Directory realm the host is part of
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.
#
# Use password server option only with security = server or if you can't
# use the DNS to locate Domain Controllers
# The argument list may include:
#   password server = My_PDC_Name [My_BDC_Name] [My_Next_BDC_Name]
# or to auto-locate the domain controller/s
#   password server = *


;   security = domain
;   passdb backend = tdbsam
;   realm = MY_REALM

;   password server = <NT-Server-Name>

# ----------------------- Domain Controller Options ------------------------
#
# Security must be set to user for domain controllers
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.
#
# Domain Master specifies Samba to be the Domain Master Browser. This
# allows Samba to collate browse lists between subnets. Don't use this
# if you already have a Windows NT domain controller doing this job
#
# Domain Logons let Samba be a domain logon server for Windows workstations.
#
# Logon Scrpit let yuou specify a script to be run at login time on the client
# You need to provide it in a share called NETLOGON
#
# Logon Path let you specify where user profiles are stored (UNC path)
#
# Various scripts can be used on a domain controller or stand-alone
# machine to add or delete corresponding unix accounts
#
;   security = user
;   passdb backend = tdbsam

;   domain master = yes
;   domain logons = yes

    # the login script name depends on the machine name
;   logon script = %m.bat
    # the login script name depends on the unix user used
;   logon script = %u.bat
;   logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%u
    # disables profiles support by specifing an empty path
;   logon path =  

;   add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd "%u" -n -g users
;   add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd "%g"
;   add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -n -c "Workstation (%u)" -M -d /nohome -s /bin/false "%u"
;   delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u"
;   delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u" "%g"
;   delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel "%g"


# ----------------------- Browser Control Options ----------------------------
#
# set local master to no if you don't want Samba to become a master
# browser on your network. Otherwise the normal election rules apply
#
# OS Level determines the precedence of this server in master browser
# elections. The default value should be reasonable
#
# Preferred Master causes Samba to force a local browser election on startup
# and gives it a slightly higher chance of winning the election
;   local master = no
;   os level = 20
;   preferred master = no

#----------------------------- Name Resolution -------------------------------
# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
#
# - WINS Support: Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable it's WINS Server
#
# - WINS Server: Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
#
# - WINS Proxy: Tells Samba to answer name resolution queries on
#   behalf of a non WINS capable client, for this to work there must be
#   at least one    WINS Server on the network. The default is NO.
#
# DNS Proxy - tells Samba whether or not to try to resolve NetBIOS names
# via DNS nslookups.

;   wins support = yes
;   wins server = 172.17.2.25
;   wins proxy = yes

;   dns proxy = no

# --------------------------- Printing Options -----------------------------
#
# Load Printers let you load automatically the list of printers rather
# than setting them up individually
#
# Cups Options let you pass the cups libs custom options, setting it to raw
# for example will let you use drivers on your Windows clients
#
# Printcap Name let you specify an alternative printcap file
#
# You can choose a non default printing system using the Printing option

    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

;   printcap name = /etc/printcap
    #obtain list of printers automatically on SystemV
;   printcap name = lpstat
;   printing = cups

# --------------------------- Filesystem Options ---------------------------
#
# The following options can be uncommented if the filesystem supports
# Extended Attributes and they are enabled (usually by the mount option
# user_xattr). Thess options will let the admin store the DOS attributes
# in an EA and make samba not mess with the permission bits.
#
# Note: these options can also be set just per share, setting them in global
# makes them the default for all shares

;   map archive = no
;   map hidden = no
;   map read only = no
;   map system = no
;   store dos attributes = yes


#============================ Share Definitions ==============================


#[homes]
#   comment = Home Directories
#   browseable = no
#   guest ok = yes
#   writable = yes
#;  valid users = %S
#;  valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    browseable = no
    guest ok = no
    writable = no
    printable = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
;   [netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   writable = no
;   share modes = no


# Un-comment the following to provide a specific roving profile share
# the default is to use the user's home directory
;   [Profiles]
;   path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
;   browseable = no
;   guest ok = yes


# A publicly accessible directory, but read only, except for people in
# the "staff" group
;   [public]
;   comment = Public Stuff
;   path = /home/samba
;   public = yes
;   writable = yes
;   printable = no
;   write list = +staff

[falcon]
        guest ok = yes
        force create mode = 777
        create mask = 777
        path = /home/falcon
    writeable = yes
        force directory mode = 777
        directory mask = 777

[oa]
        locking = no
#       writable = yes
        path = /u/oa
        force directory mode = 0666
        force create mode = 0666
#       comment = home directories
#       case sensitive = yes
```

I tried changing the log level to 3. Below is the /var/log/samba/smbd.log after the latest restart of the smb service

```
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/connection.c:yield_connection(69)
  Yielding connection to 
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/server.c:exit_server_common(782)
  Server exit (normal exit)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/connection.c:yield_connection(69)
  Yielding connection to 
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/connection.c:yield_connection(76)
  yield_connection: tdb_delete for name  failed with error Record does not exist.
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/server.c:exit_server_common(782)
  Server exit (normal exit)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 0] smbd/server.c:main(958)
  smbd version 3.0.33-3.39.el5_8 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2008
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] param/loadparm.c:do_section(3825)
  Processing section "[printers]"
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] param/loadparm.c:do_section(3825)
  Processing section "[falcon]"
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] param/loadparm.c:do_section(3825)
  Processing section "[oa]"
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] param/loadparm.c:lp_add_ipc(2733)
  adding IPC service
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] printing/pcap.c:pcap_cache_reload(117)
  reloading printcap cache
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] printing/pcap.c:pcap_cache_reload(223)
  reload status: ok
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] printing/pcap.c:pcap_cache_reload(117)
  reloading printcap cache
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] printing/pcap.c:pcap_cache_reload(223)
  reload status: ok
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] lib/interface.c:add_interface(81)
  added interface ip=172.19.50.30 bcast=172.19.50.255 nmask=255.255.255.0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/server.c:main(996)
  loaded services
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/server.c:main(1011)
  Becoming a daemon.
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] lib/tallocmsg.c:register_msg_pool_usage(105)
  Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] lib/dmallocmsg.c:register_dmalloc_msgs(75)
  Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 2
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-22-1-0]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-5-2]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-5-11]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(250)
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/util_seaccess.c:se_access_check(251)
  se_access_check: user sid is S-1-22-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-32-544
  se_access_check: also S-1-1-0
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-2
  se_access_check: also S-1-5-11
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-5-21-3965382125-1125146146-860252422-501]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-22-2-99]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-5-2]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] lib/privileges.c:get_privileges(261)
  get_privileges: No privileges assigned to SID [S-1-5-32-546]
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:push_sec_ctx(208)
  push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/uid.c:push_conn_ctx(358)
  push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:set_sec_ctx(241)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] smbd/sec_ctx.c:pop_sec_ctx(356)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 3] printing/printing.c:start_background_queue(1388)
  start_background_queue: Starting background LPQ thread
[2013/09/25 11:53:11, 2] smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd(466)
  waiting for a connection
```

I've run through the basic troubleshooting guide here to no avail
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/diagnosis.html

My last attempt was to try to copy a working smb.conf file from another SAMBA server in the environment and restart SMB services. No dice and same result.

Any tips or ideas from here on how to determine why I cannot browse the SAMBA shares configured on this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that can prevent Samba to work well on CentOS: the firewall and SELinux.
Check the 
[official Centos wiki for Samba](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba) for a more accurate guide.

Comment: This wiki solved my problem, thank you! I had an incorrect entry in iptables and it was not committing the changes. Once I corrected the entry everything worked. Many thanks!